# (Im)Possible 8-Puzzle

Tags: no-computers, sliding-blocks

[image]

> Can you solve this [8-puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) in 16 moves or less?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

16 moves is the minimum possible. (I checked by computer, but solved it first without one.)

> ```
>  P O S 
>  L . S 
>  E B I 
>  
>  P O S   P O S   P O S   P O S   P O S   . O S   O . S 
>  L S .   L S I   L S I   L S I   . S I   P S I   P S I 
>  E B I   E B .   E . B   . E B   L E B   L E B   L E B 
>  
>  O S S 
>  P . I 
>  L E B 
>  
>  O S S   O S S   O S S   O S .   O . S   . O S   P O S 
>  P E I   P E I   P E .   P E S   P E S   P E S   . E S 
>  L . B   L B .   L B I   L B I   L B I   L B I   L B I 
>  
>  P O S 
>  E . S 
>  L B I
> ```

Explanation:

> By letting the blank go around 3/4 of the perimeter, you can cyclically shift 7 of the tiles, leaving one corner stationary. That corner tile is therefore jumped over by an adjacent tile, swapping two tiles relatively speaking.
>  By doing this twice, in opposite directions, on opposite corners, the effect is of swapping the two opposite corners with adjacent edge tiles, i.e. S-S and L-E.